# Excel 07: Sum Cells of Column B By Date in Column A And Report To Cell C

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

So basically I have a worksheet like so,

[image]

The data is manually entered in, column A is the date, the values are column E. Everything else is arbitrary and filled with x's. Basically what I want to do is have the data in column E summed and reported in a different cell when the date in column A is equal to today's date for that row. I've tried a couple uses of sumif and the like but I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong! So for example, when date = 9/23/15 the cell should report 600, and this updates by day and by extra data entered. Sorry for any confusion! And thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know about Pivot Tables and are you sure they don't solve your problem? https://support.office.com/en-MY/Article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can indeed be accomplished by using `SUMIF`. `SUMIF` allows you to specify a criteria range and a sum range separately. In the following example, the criteria range `A:A` (entire column A) will be matched for the criteria (`D1`) and the values in the sum range `B:B` (entire column B) will be summed if the criteria is satisfied.

```
=SUMIF(A:A, D1,B:B )
```

Note that you can also specify a normal range, but if you do, make sure to use absolute references with the `$` character, otherwise your formula will shift in an undesired way when you copy it down. (for example, `$A$1:$A$7` instead of `A:A`)

[image: example]

Comment: Given the question, I'm thinking that the desired equation would be `=sumif(A:A,A1,B:B)`

Comment: @Dane I wasn't sure where the actual date criteria are located (corresponding to column D in my screenshot), so that's why I instead provided a simple example that can be applied to any situation rather than writing a formula to accommodate this one specific situation.

Comment: So this is exactly what I was looking for, but for some reason excel wasn't accepting some stretch of the table, and after the edits, everything worked nicely. Thank you!